# Дополнительная отправка AJAX

Tags: post, javascript, html, ajax

Есть AJAX код, он собирает информацию при нажатии на кнопку, соединенную в форму с  `<input>`. Проблема в том, что он отправляет это все 2-3 раза, как я понимаю.

Помогите избавится от данной проблемы.

Вот сам код - http://pastebin.com/MuzMtUZ7

```js
$(".method").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $form = $this.find(".form_test_form");
    var responseBody = $this.find(".test_form_response");
    var responseField = responseBody.find(".response-field");
    var requestURL = window.location.host + $form.attr('action');
    $this.find(".request-url-field").text(requestURL);
    $this.find(".get-request").click(function () {
        var url = $form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            processData: true,
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            headers:({"Auth-Secret":$("input[id='authpass']").val()}),
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                var msg = "status: " + request.status + " (" + request.statusText + ")\n\n" + data;
                responseField.text(msg);
            },
            error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var msg = "status: " + request.status + " (" + request.statusText + ")";
                responseField.text(msg);
                if (request.status == 403 || request.status == 404){
                    wgpass();
                }
            }
        }).always(function () {
        });
        return false;
    });
    $this.find(".post-request").click(function () {
    });

    $form.bind('submit', function () {
        $(".response-field").text("HTTP request is processed - please wait");
        var submitParams = $form.serialize();
        var metadataBackup = "";
        if($form.attr('id') == "kaltura") {
            metadataBackup = $("#kaltura_base64").val();
            //alert(btoa($("#kaltura_base64").val()));
            $("#kaltura_base64").val(btoa(btoa($("#kaltura_base64").val())));
        }


        var submitParams = $form.serialize();
        var url = $form.attr('action');
        var tempURL = window.location.host + url;
        $(".request-url-field").text(tempURL).show();
        var valid = 0;  // fix bug: post requests are issued twice (mask off long request)
        if (url=="/api/timestamp") { valid = 1; }
        if (url=="/api/text") { valid = 1; }
        if (submitParams.indexOf("&")==-1) { valid = 1; }       // no "&"
        else {
            if ((submitParams.indexOf("&",(submitParams.indexOf("&")+1))==-1)&&((url=="/api/settings")||(url=="/api/audio")))   // 1x "&"
            { valid = 1; }
            if ((submitParams.indexOf("&",(submitParams.indexOf("&",(submitParams.indexOf("&")+1))+1))==-1)&&(url=="/api/date") || (url=="/api/record/metadata"))   // 2x "&"
            { valid = 1; }
            if ((submitParams.indexOf("&",(submitParams.indexOf("&",(submitParams.indexOf("&",(submitParams.indexOf("&")+1))+1))+1))==-1)&&(url=="/api/record/metadata"))   // 3x "&"
            { valid = 1; }
            if ((submitParams.indexOf("&",(submitParams.indexOf("&",(submitParams.indexOf("&",(submitParams.indexOf("&",(submitParams.indexOf("&")+1))+1))+1))+1))==-1)&&(url=="/api/ftp")) //4x "&"
            { valid = 1; }
        }
        if($form.attr('id') == "kaltura") {
            $("#kaltura_base64").val(metadataBackup);
            //alert(submitParams);
        }


        //alert("url " + url + " post " + submitParams + " " + " " + $this.id + " " + $form.attr('id'));
        var result = $( "input[id='checksave']" ).prop( "checked" );
        if (result) { submitParams = "action=save&" + submitParams; }
        if (((url=="/api/input/edid")&&(submitParams.substring(0, 5) == "base=")) || (url=="/api/record/metadata") || (url=="/api/api") || (url=="/api/ftp")) {
            $(".post-field").text(submitParams.substring(0, 40) + " ...").show();
        } else {
            $(".post-field").text(submitParams).show();
        }
        if (valid == 1) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                processData: true,
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                data: submitParams,
                headers:({"Auth-Secret":$("input[id='authpass']").val()}),
                success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                    var msg = "status: " + request.status + " (" + request.statusText + ")\n\n" + data;
                    $(".response-field").text(msg);
                },
                error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var msg = "status: " + request.status + " (" + request.statusText + ")";
                    $(".response-field").text(msg);
                    if (request.status == 403 || request.status == 404){
                        wgpass();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".response-field").text("HTTP request blocked!");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: На вашу кнопку несколько раз навешивается событие. Т.е. вы нажимаете кнопку, а на кнопке висит не одно, а несколько событий.

Comment: покажи слепому точнее, пожалуйста )

Comment: @Insider я не знаю ваш html код, я не знаю, сколько раз объявляется фрагмент кода, возможно, он подгружается несколько раз. Добавьте логгирование перед отправками запросов и смотрите, в чём дело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вашей кнопки, полагаю, стоит атрибут type="submit". это говорит о том, что при ее нажатии форма выполняет запрос. плюс ко всему javascript тоже выполняет запрос. 
избавьтесь от submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="send form">
```

поменяйте на

```
<input type="button" value="send form" id="sendForm">
```

button - та же визуальная кнопка, но она не отправляет форму на выполнение запроса

и отредактируйте javascript 'активацию' формы:

на 35й строке

```
$form.bind('submit', function () {
```

поменяйте на

```
$("#sendForm").on( "click", function() {
```